# Does silent post URL expects any response from our server?

Tags: authorize.net, silent-post

Does silentpostURL expects any response from the server?

If Yes,

1. What are the possible response values?
2. If the response is false(0) then will the transaction for that month will be voided?

In a monthly recurring subscription, I have to stop charging the user for 1 or 2 months and after that it has to be started again. Is there any way to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Silent Post does not expect a response from your server like Relay Response does.

> In a monthly recurring subscription, I have to stop charging the user for 1 or 2 months and after that it has to be started again. Is there any way to do it programatically?

You would need to cancel the first subscription and then create a new one when you want the subscription to start again.